# shell script question on homestead

Tags: nginx

I added a nginx config rewrite rule to remove static asset numbers from file names. It works great on the server config file.

```
    # enable static file caching
    location ~* (.+)\.(?:\d+)\.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp)$ {
     try_files $uri $1.$2;
    }
```

However I'm now trying to use a custome serve-craft.sh on my homestead local to replace the default serve.laravel.sh. (to prevent losing my nginx config every time I do a reload --provision).

I'm not familiar with sh syntax and the following doesn't seem to work when I load the sh by adding a "type:craft" to my homestead.yaml
I suspect the try_files line has syntax error

How could I rewrite this in shell script?

Any idea anyone?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to accomplish what you're trying to accomplish would be to utilize the `after.sh` shell script that Homestead provides. Check out [Extending Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/homestead#extending-homestead) and [Local Development with Vagrant / Homestead](https://nystudio107.com/blog/local-development-with-vagrant-homestead)